# HTML div width and textbox width is not equal

Tags: html, css

I tried following code in HTML.

But unable to understand why the text box and div width is not same size.

Here is what i have tried.

```
<style>
.test
{
  border:1px solid red;width:100px;height:30px;padding:3px;
}
</style>

<div class="test">div</div>
<input type="text" value="text box" class="test" />
```

The following i got in firefox.

[image]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/c4tQB/ aren't they the same ?

Comment: but in firefox im seeing difference. may i know please

Comment: some browsers add extra padding and margins so use a reset 

`* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`

Comment: Nope tried on firefox and chrome. I see the same width.

Comment: Please wait i will attach my screen shot..

Comment: are you using some other style sheets too ? Is the file stand alone ?

Comment: i just using this code only.In my application i faced this issue. so i tried it separately.

Comment: Tested @kritya's fiddle and works fine in chrome, firefox, opera.

Comment: Inspect this in firebug (css, html layout).

Comment: Tested in firefox, works fine.

Comment: But when I make a new html document and put in your code, They don't have the same width. Weird. I'll have a look at this.

Comment: I am facing this issue in this firfox version. I didnt checked with other versions.

Comment: @suresh.g Doubt it has anything to do with your problem but developing a page/site in a beta version of a browser is just asking for a headache. i.e. Unexpected results are to be expected. ;)

Comment: its fine.. thank you to every one.

Comment: Yes, Works fine in chrome and firefox

Answer (score 1):

it works fine in FF, IE, CHROME. Try after removing `padding:3px;`

code something like this:

```
 <style>
    .test
    {
        border:1px solid red;width:100px;height:30px;
    }
</style>
```

Let me know it will helps you or not ?

Comment: better set padding to zero. inputs often have by default own paddings